# PHP Mysql evitar cadastro no banco em letras maiúsculas

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia,

Tenho um banco de dados, onde os usuários inserem notícias diversas.

Já conversei com todos eles, para não colocarem letras maiúsculas na inclusão, pois deixa o projeto esteticamente feio.

Existe um jeito de emitir um alerta, ao cadastrar? Por exemplo: "Seu título está em letras maiúsculas, favor corrigir".

Como poderia gerar esse alerta, usando o código abaixo?

```
<?php
require 'conexao1.php';
header ("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$titulo                 = addslashes ($_POST['titulo']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (titulo) VALUES ('$titulo')";

mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if ($sql) {
echo "<script> alert('Título inserido com sucesso!');
}

?>
```

Andei buscando algumas informações, mas confesso que não fiz nada parecido ainda.

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda!

Comment: Se for exibir um aviso faça por javascript, se for gravar o título enviado em maiusculas, converta em minusculas no php e grava sem avisar o usuário

Comment: Eu prefiro o aviso, porque se o usuário colocar um nome próprio por exemplo, vai ficar tudo em minúsculo, e incorreto na visualização. "paulo" no lugar de "Paulo" ou "brasil" no lugar de "Brasil".

Comment: Faz sentido mesmo, nesse caso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usualmente eu uso uma margem de tolerância. Você pode fazer algo nesse sentido:

```
function porcentagem_maiusculas( $string ) {
   $count = 0;
   $len = mb_strlen( $string );

   for( $i = $len - 1; $i >=0 ; --$i ) {
      $char = mb_substr( $string, $i, 1 );
      $count += ( mb_strtolower( $char ) == $char ? 0 : 1 );
   }
   return 100 * $count / $len;
}
```

Aí, para usar o alerta, basta algo do tipo:

```
if( porcentagem_maiusculas( $titulo ) > 40 ) {
   echo 'Você usou maiúsculas demais no título. Escreva direitinho, senão não aceitamos. Por favor, verifique!';
} else {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (titulo) VALUES ('$titulo')";
   mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );
   echo "<script>alert('Título inserido com sucesso!')</script>";
}
```

Veja uma demonstração da função no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/AZb3vC)**.

A recomendação é dar uma tolerância razoável (inicialmente 40 ou 50%), para que a pessoa possa usar siglas corretamente em maiúsculas no título, mas ao mesmo tempo deixar os tiozinhos do CAPS LOCK no eixo.

Nas minhas aplicações eu uso um *approach* um pouco mais complexo, mudando a tolerância de acordo com o tamanho da string. Strings curtas mais tolerantes, e à medida que aumenta, a tolerância cai, mas talvez seja um pouco de exagero.

Answer (score 0):

Uma saída é você fazer com que o título fique em minúsculo. Para isso utilize a função `strtolower()`:

```
<?php
require 'conexao1.php';
header ("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$titulo                 = addslashes(strtolower($_POST['titulo']));

$sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (titulo) VALUES ('$titulo')";

mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if ($sql) {
echo "<script> alert('Título inserido com sucesso!');
}

?>
```

Assim qualquer caractere que ele colocar em maiúsculo ficará minúsculo.

Comment: A ideia é ótima, @AlissonAcioli, mas vai ficar tudo em minúsculo, inclusive os nomes próprios, não vai ficar bacana na visualização. Prefiro emitir o aviso, assim "ensino" também ao usuário.